# EntityState.Modified does work differently on updating in EF Core vs EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

When I run this method with EF 6 the student was updated!

```
 public async Task Update(Student student)
        {
            context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

When I run this method with EF 7 nothing has changed in the database!

What do I wrong? I do not want to retrieve the entity first to update it!

**UPDATE**

I put a try/catch around the SaveChanges and got this error message:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Students_Schoolclasses_SchoolclassId". The conflict occurred in database "TGBData", table "dbo.Schoolclasses", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is it a problem when I set the WHOLE entity state to modified, when one of its properties (e.g. Student.SchoolclassId) is a foreign key?

**UPDATE 2**

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentsTests = new HashSet<StudentTest>();
        StudentsSubjects = new HashSet<SubjectStudent>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ISet<StudentTest> StudentsTests { get; set; }
    public ISet<SubjectStudent> StudentsSubjects { get; set; }
    public Schoolclass Schoolclass { get; set; }
    public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
}

public class Schoolclass
{
    public Schoolclass()
    {
        Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        Tests = new HashSet<Test>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public ISet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ISet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }
    public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
}
```

When the Update method is entered the student FirstName/LastName properties have the new values!

Comment: That works in EF Core the same way as in EF 6. Use a profiler to see what SQL is being executed.

Comment: Funny... that savechanges does never show up in my sql profiler !!!

Comment: Of course other stuff shows in my sql profiler, that is not the problem...

Comment: Pascal, I use this approach too and everything works... Can you make a [mcv example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (in EF Core) and upload it to github/...?

Comment: Hm this is really odd because I had that similar problem already with another type of entity. I will first try a minimal repro with a new application - maybe in my application something is wrong...

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't fix a vague question by a bounty. You don't show what `student` looks like when it enters the method, or what the class and its associations looks like. Pretty essential information.

Comment: @GertArnold See my update, hope it fits for you now ;-)

Comment: What is the value of student.SchoolclassId and student.Schoolclass before calling save changes in your Update method? If you break a relationship or try to update an entity pointing to an invalid foreign key, you will see that error.

Comment: damn i feel thats it... When I do context.student.single by studentId do not need the schoolclassId therefore the update works by retrieving the student, argh....50 points :/ :P :P I must say the error message is really MISLEADING - shouting to EF Core team -

Comment: @Tom Ok you were right! 50 points are yours! Now it works. So the context.Entry method always needs the PK + FK of the entity, PK alone is not enough! Any idea why? A PK is enough to identity a record correctly actually...

Comment: Well, you simply mark all fields as modified if you mark an entity as modified, including FK values (they're just primitive properties). So if the FK value doesn't exist... boom. An alternative could be to mark specific properties as modified.

Comment: I did that:  var entry = context.Entry(student);
            entry.Property(p => p.FirstName).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(p => p.LastName).IsModified = true;
But after savechanges() the data was NOT updated in the database. There occured no exception.

Comment: @Pascal i would recommend you implementing [EF Generic Data Access Layer](http://blog.falafel.com/implement-step-step-generic-repository-pattern-c/). It will perform the update you are asking and it will give you more flexibility. just give it a look

Comment: @Pascal, how does one collect on this bounty? :) To answer your question -- PK+FK are needed because you are attaching an in-memory object to a new context. Once you attach the object and mark it as modified, since the context was not tracking changes, it attempts to update the entire object. If FK is null in memory, it thinks you broke the relationship and commits your object. When it goes to update FK to null, boom exception!

Comment: Can you share more details? It sounds to me that it may be related to the way you are handling the operations. I.E: You are trying to modify an object already being tracked by EF somewhere else in your code. It's hard to tell with the information shared.

Comment: @Tom Yup that was it. The reason why it worked before in other scenarios was because I used SingleOrDefault by primary key but I only did that because the marking whole entity caused trouble as I forgot of the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is stating that your Student has SchoolclassId and that value does not exist in the foreign table which is Id in Schoolclasses table.

Check the value of SchoolclassId before calling SaveChanges. Most likely this value does not exist in Schoolclasses table.

In other words this error is not because of EF 6 vs EF 7 but due to a foreign key not being found in the related table.

Comment: Finally someone copy/paste my comment! ;-)